# Category View All option only shows 3 products

Tags: category

Using Magento 1.91

If a user goes to any category page and clicks "All" in the toolbar, they will only see 3 products. This is not the case on the search pages, however, and clicking "All" there will show all products (and there are significantly more products in search than in the categories, so it's not a memory issue)

I've added different limits into the toolbar, 8, 12, 24 and those all work fine. The only issue is on "All"

I also removed the custom theme and I am still seeing the issue.

Any ideas on where to attack this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See this setting in admin

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog (left menu) -> Frontend -> Allow All Products per Page
```

Set this value to "Yes" and try.

Comment: This is set to "Yes" already.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and spend many hours trying to solve it.
My dev now made a dirty 'hack' - for those interested;

pp/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php (line 227)

```
    /* FIX: SHOW ALL ITEMS */
    if($this->getLimit() == 'all'){
      $limit = 1000000;
    } else {
      $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    }
```

Beware it's a CORE hack, you will lose the 'fix' when upgrading.
And it's more a bandage then a fix.
But if anyone else have a better solution then please share it.